# NewRelic Invalid License key

Tags: ruby, heroku, newrelic

I installed NewRelic through a Heroku addon. After following instructions to install and configure the app on, I got this error:

```
NewRelic::Agent::LicenseException: Invalid license key, please visit support.newrelic.com
```

My license key is valid and set properly as an environmental variable in production.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I used at an old version of the `newrelic_rpm` gem.

An gem update fixed the issue:

```
Installing newrelic_rpm 4.1.0.333 (was 3.17.2.327)
```